# Communication between processes using WCF and F#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, f#, protobuf-net

I would like to make a simple one to one communication between two long time running F# processes using F#. They will exchange information regularly every ca. 5 seconds. Until now, I have reached this point:

```
#r "System.ServiceModel"
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"
//#r @"d:\DLL\Protobuf\protobuf-net.dll"
#time "on"

open System.ServiceModel

[<ServiceContract>]
type IService =
  [<OperationContract>]
  // [<ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehavior>]
  abstract Test: float [] [] [] -> string

type Service () =
  interface IService with
    member o.Test data = sprintf "Hello, %A" data

let server = System.Threading.Thread (fun () ->
  let svh = new ServiceHost (typeof<Service>)
  svh.AddServiceEndpoint (typeof<IService>, NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/123") |> ignore
  svh.Open () )

server.IsBackground <- true
server.Start()

let scf: IService = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel (NetNamedPipeBinding(), EndpointAddress "net.pipe://localhost/123")
let rnd = System.Random ()
let arr =
  Array.init 100 (fun i ->
    Array.init 10 (fun j ->
      Array.init 10 (fun k ->
        rnd.NextDouble()
  )))

printfn "%s" (scf.Test arr)
```

I get a plenty of different exceptions mainly due to different WCF security limits.

My questions are

1. What do I need to do at minimum to make it work?
2. Did I write the code correctly to make the communication as fast as possible?
3. I have tried to include ProtoBuf serializer (see ProtoBehavior in the code) to make the serialization even faster. Did I implemented it correctly? How do I know that WCF actually uses it or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increase [MaxReceivedMessageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) property on the binding from it's default value of 65536 on both the client and server to accommodate the volume of data you are transferring.

You can use a [Message Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to check if WCF is actually using the ProtoBuf serializer (which it isn't). The ProtoBehavior appears to only be applied to values with a DataContract/ProtoContract attribute specified. So in the modified example below I have created a Vector record type, also marked with the F# 3 [CLIMutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) attribute, to wrap the arrays:

```
#r "System.ServiceModel"
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"
#r "protobuf-net.dll"
#time "on"

open System.ServiceModel
open System.Runtime.Serialization

[<DataContract; ProtoBuf.ProtoContract; CLIMutable>]
type Vector<'T> = { [<DataMember; ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)>] Values : 'T[] }

[<ServiceContract>]
type IService =
  [<OperationContract>]
  [<ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehavior>]
  abstract Test: Vector<Vector<Vector<float>>> -> string

type Service () =
  interface IService with
    member o.Test data = sprintf "Hello, %A" data

let server = System.Threading.Thread (fun () ->
  let svh = new ServiceHost (typeof<Service>)
  let binding = NetNamedPipeBinding()
  binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize <- binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize * 4L
  svh.AddServiceEndpoint (typeof<IService>, binding, "net.pipe://localhost/123") |> ignore
  svh.Open () )

server.IsBackground <- true
server.Start()

let scf: IService = 
   let binding = NetNamedPipeBinding()
   binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize <- binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize * 4L
   ChannelFactory.CreateChannel (binding, EndpointAddress "net.pipe://localhost/123")
let rnd = System.Random ()
let arr =
  { Values = Array.init 100 (fun i ->
   { Values =
      Array.init 10 (fun j ->
         { Values =Array.init 10 (fun k -> rnd.NextDouble()) }
      )}
   )}

printfn "%s" (scf.Test arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer "3" : use wireshark to inspect the data on the wire, or otherwise time it / measure re bandwidth. Try it with/without protobu-net enabled, and compare. A protobuf message will have a chunk of binary data instead of XML.

Note: if you are using protobuf-net here, enabling MTOM will shave a little bit more (if it is available for your chosen transport).