# Sharing data into an embedded FSI session

Tags: f#

I have an existing application in which I'd like the ability to have my own FSI session.  Although rather than a standard FSI session, I'd like the ability to pre-populate the FSI session with data from my application.

So for example.  Within my app, an existing process happens.  Data is created, and I launch the FSI session.  The FSI session, will be pre-loaded with the data that has already been computed.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: One ugly way would be to output a script that was then read in to fsi using the command line

Answer (score 2):

The most correct answer for today is to use [F# Compiler Services](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/). Interactive Service allow [to embed F# interactive in your application](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html).

Other option:

1. You can to format data as a valid F# code and execute it into FSI, or to serialize data as a string and deserialize using F#. In this case, the article "[Using FSI to execute F# code from a .NET app](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Using-FSI-to-execute-FSharp-code-from-a-dot-NET-app.aspx)" by Mathias Brandewinder may be useful for you.
2. Prepare an API that provide an access to your data. For example, based on the [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) that become available starting from .NET 4.0. Immediately after start of FSI session to add reference to your assembly (using [FSI directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx) #r) and get data through custom API.
3. Use WCF to communicate between two processes. See [answer from Phillip Trelford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527619/communication-between-processes-using-wcf-and-f/14757118#14757118).

Comment: When FSI starts wouldn't it be another application instance. In this case how would the singleton be able to be shared?

Comment: For example we can use [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) for creating shared memory for interprocess communication